# Erro ao instalar API goslate para python em Windows

Tags: python, google-translate

Estou obtendo esse resultado quando tento instalar a API goslate, que é uma Api do Google mais otimizada pra mexer com traduções e outras coisas mais.

```
C:\Users\chris\Documents\PyCharm Projects\Integrador\goslate-1.5.1>py setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 8, in <module>
      import goslate as module
  File "C:\Users\chris\Documents\PyCharm Projects\Integrador\goslate-1.5.1\goslate.py", line 33, in <module>
      import concurrent.futures
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\futures-3.0.3-py3.5.egg\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
      from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\futures-3.0.3-py3.5.egg\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 355
      raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Parece que está dando um problema no módulo `futures`, e eu já até baixei essa lib `futures` mais recente e a instalei tranquilamente, só que não adiantou de nada.

**Pergunta**

Alguém sabe o que posso fazer para solucionar esse problema?

*P.S. Estou utilizando python versão 3.5.1*

Comment: Tentou fazer a instalação no Python 2.7 ?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho, goslate diz que é compatível com 3.4+.

Comment: Como vc esta fazendo a instalação?

Comment: Eu preciso fazer isso no Python mais recente por conta de outros recursos do meu trabalho. A instalação é justamente o que está aí baixei o arquivo e fui instalá-lo. Goslate é compatível, só esse problema no `future` que tá atrasando o negócio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como é possível ver [nessa issue](https://github.com/agronholm/pythonfutures/issues/41) do repositório da futures, o futures é um módulo feito pra programas da versão 2.x serem compatíveis com *features* da versão 3.x, então não faz muito sentido instalar o módulo future para as versões 3.x.

Logo, caso desinstalar a futures deve resolver o seu problema.

Outro adição é que, talvez, seja mais simples usar o [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) para instalar esses pacotes.

Comment: Ok cara, desistalei tudo aqui e fiz pelo `pip` e funcionou certinho. Valeu!